# Decomposition of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $\textbf{F}_q(t)\otimes_{\textbf{F}_q(t^q)}\textbf{F}_q(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I have two questions about splitting of the tensor product into the product of fields

1. How can one find a decomposition of

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$

and

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$$

into the direct product of fields?

2. Let $\textbf{F}_q$ be a field with $q$ elements. Is it possible to decompose $$\textbf{F}_q(t)\otimes_{\textbf{F}_q(t^q)}\textbf{F}_q(t)$$

into the direct product of fields?

Thank you.

$\textbf{Update}.$

To answer the first question I have the following argument.
Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ are the field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ I have

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]/(x^2-2)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),$$

and

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)\otimes_\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})[x]/(x^2-2)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}).$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The second of your isomorphisms is correct. The first is not. What would $\mathbb Q\left(x\right)/\left(x^2-4\right)$ be? Surely not $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Why is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-4)$?

Comment: It isn't. This is just an example of where your logic goes wrong.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Actually, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]/(x^2-2)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\oplus\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: darij grinberg, thanx for your cirrection!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $[F_q(t) : F_q(t^q)] = q$. So, using a dimension argument over $F_q(t^q)$ you can see that
$$\dim F_q(t) \otimes F_q(t) = q^2$$
while
$$\dim F_q(t) \oplus F_q(t) = 2q $$
so they are not isomorphic for $q \neq 2$.