# What do the prime ideals of $A \otimes_C B$ look like?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, schemes, fibre-product

Let $A, B, C$ be rings and suppose I have $\phi: C \to A$ and $\psi: C \to B$ so that the tensor product $A \otimes_C B$ makes sense. I want to prove that given prime ideals $P$ of $A$ and $Q$ of $B$ such that $\phi^{-1} (P) = \psi^{-1} (Q)$, there exists a prime ideal $R$ of $A \otimes_C B$ such that
$P = i^{-1}(R)$ and $Q = j^{-1} (R)$ where $i: A \to A \otimes_C B$ and $j: B \to A \otimes_C B$. How can I prove that such prime ideal exists? (I am asking this because I want to prove that if I take a fibre product of schemes then I can find a point $z \in X \times Y$ above $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.)

Comment: Points from the tensor product $Frac(A/P) \otimes Frac(B/Q)$ (above $Frac(C/\psi^{-1}(Q))$) will suit your needs.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out what prime ideals of $A \otimes_C B$ look like in general, for your application it would suffice to find a field $K$ and homomorphisms $A \to K$ and $B \to K$ whose kernels are the prime ideals you are interested in and such that the composites $C \to A \to K$ and $C \to B \to K$ are equal. Then there will be a homomorphism $A \otimes_C B \to K$ whose kernel is prime and pulls back to the prime ideals you started with.

Comment: @Mindlack What is the tensor product over? and how do I know this tensor product is non-zero?

Comment: If $C=\mathbb{Z}, A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\mathbb{F}_p$, then your tensor product will be the zero ring and have no prime ideals.

Comment: @Johnny T. : I already wrote in my comment what the tensor product was above. It’s a tensor product over a field of field extensions of said field (so nonzero vector spaces), so (using eg bases) is nonzero.

Comment: [Lemma 26.17.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JT) in the stacks project gives a relatively explicit description: the prime ideals of $A\otimes_C B$ are in bijection with sets of tuples $(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{p}',\mathfrak{q}),$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ (respectively, $\mathfrak{p}'$) is a prime of $A$ (respectively $B$) such that $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{P} = \psi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}')$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})\otimes_{\kappa(\mathfrak{P})}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}')$ (here, $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) = A_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}.$).

Comment: [Continued] This might not be totally satisfying on its own, but it reduces you to thinking about the case when $A,B,$ and $C$ are all fields. This situation is not completely trivial, but has been discussed in several cases which might be helpful for you, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698603/describe-prime-ideals-and-krull-dimension-of-overline-mathbbq-otimes-ma), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769792/prime-ideals-of-bar-mathbbq-otimes-mathbbq-bar-mathbbq), ...

Comment: [Continued] [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259645/decomposition-of-the-tensor-product-mathbbq-p-otimes-mathbbq-mathbbq), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401266/tensor-product-of-a-number-field-k-and-the-p-adic-integers), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020495/decomposition-of-mathbbq-sqrt2-otimes-mathbbq-mathbbq-sqrt3) to start. The proof of the lemma in my first comment might also resolve your question on its own.